# Using NHibernate & the repository pattern to return a child collection of items that don't exist

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate and the repository pattern in my latest app. I have 3 tables/entities: Regions, Tags and Translations with the following schema.

```
Regions 

Id
RegionName


Tags

Id
FilePath
FileName
TagContent


Translations

Id
RegionId
TagId
Translation
```

The tags table contains a list of phrases (tags), the application allows a user to specify a translation for each tag. So lets say the tags table contains 50 phrases (tags). After the user has translated 10 of those tags into Spanish for instance, then the region entity for Spanish will have a child collection of 10 translated tags. I'd like to be able have a property/method on the region class that returns a child collection of the 40 untranslated tags.

I realise I can achieve this by retrieving all the tags and testing to see if the tag exists or not in the region entity's tranlated tags child collection. But that all happens on the client. I want it to happen on the server (let SQL do the work).

Can this be achieved with NHibernate. What would my mappings be (I'm using FluentNHibernate)

Comment: Does a Translation record exist for translations that don't exist yet? I mean, is the record there, but with a NULL Translation field? If so, then you can retrieve the entire collection of Translations for the Region and filter on the Translation field being null...

Comment: ...If this is not the case, then what you are asking amounts to this: will NHibernate return a list of Translation objects `that don't exist`? No, it can't. What would they look like?

Comment: You could use a linq or hql query to return a list of the Tags for which no related Translation record exists though. But there's no way to express this in terms of object associations that I can think of.

Comment: Thanks David I believe you and Jamie are correct I'm reasonably new to NHibernate and wanted to make sure I hadn't missed anything obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, retrieving this collection should be a query in a repository class, not part of your domain model. You can write the query using HQL, Criteria, or LINQ. If you state your preference I'm sure someone will reply with an example.

Comment: Yes I think you're correct (see my last comment to David). I'll take your advise and have a go at adding a linq query to a repository to return the collection I need.